# Setting context name in thymeleaf with spring boot deployed on tomcat8 behind apache reverse proxy

Tags: spring, apache, spring-boot, thymeleaf, reverse-proxy

I am trying to :

- **setup a sub domain**, in which root path `/` will proxy local tomcat's running thymeleaf + spring boot app at `http://localhost:8080/myuiapp/`,
- With a flexibility that I can change the context path to `/application` or `/demo` or `/anything` in future (with just apache config changes) without any codebase or tomcat config changes.

The problem I'm facing is:- thymeleaf is not changing context name when deployed on standalone tomcat8. (I got to know that context path property affect only in embedded tomcat server)

So `th:href="@{/assets/vendors/global/vendors.bundle.css}"` is computed as `href=/myuiapp/assets/vendors/global/vendors.bundle.css` always.

Here's one of the virtual host config that I've tried:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName foo.domain.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.domain.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.domain.com/privkey.pem

        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myuiapp/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myuiapp/

        ProxyPass /newapp/ http://localhost:8080/myuiapp/
        ProxyPassReverse /newapp/ http://localhost:8080/myuiapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried the following things:

1) Apache sending headers to application and application respecting those headers

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost on
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
```

`server.use-forward-headers=true`

2) Setting context path manually

```
System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", contextPath)
```

3) Server-relative URLs in Thymeleaf - [link](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) (It solves my first problem of Root `/` context path but not `/any` context path)

```
<a th:href="@{~/billing-app/showDetails.htm}">
```

Need your help in setting dynamic context-name, when we deploy on standalone tomcat which is recognised by thymeleaf as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I had the following line in the html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/stylesheet.css}"/>
```

and the stylesheet was found at `http://localhost:8321/css/disclaimer.css` and correctly applied (notice the lack of application name on the path).
However on production the new link to the css was `https://example.com/app-name/css/stylesheet.css`
but in the html it was still pointing wrongly to `https://example.com/css/stylesheet.css`

To fix this I had to remove the initial `/` from href like so:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/stylesheet.css}"/>
```

and the css applied both locally and in production.

Answer (score 0):

I stood at the same question and I solved the problem with thymeleaf and javascript as following.

Lets say my context-path is `/app/`

In Thymeleaf you can get it via:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        let contextPath    = /*[[@{/}]]*/
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```